# MongoDB cursor inconsistent behaviour

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to understand this behavior in mongo. Deleting very first document its reflected in cursor, subsequently it's not..

```
use movies;
> db.imdb.insert({name:"Titanic", "genre":"drama", rating:"9.5"});
> db.imdb.insert({name:"Die Hard 1", "genre":"action", rating:"9"});
> db.imdb.insert({name:"Die Hard 2", "genre":"action", rating:"9"});
> db.imdb.insert({name:"Die Hard 3", "genre":"action", rating:"9"});
> db.imdb.insert({name:"Die Hard 4", "genre":"action", rating:"4"});
> cursor=db.imdb.find();null;
cursor.count();
5
> db.imdb.deleteOne({name:"Titanic"});
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
> cursor.count();
4
> cursor.next();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7eb82354a5c4cc4848a116"),
        "name" : "Die Hard 1",
        "genre" : "action",
        "rating" : "9"
}
> db.imdb.deleteOne({name:"Die Hard 2"});
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
> cursor.count();
3
> cursor.next();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7eb82354a5c4cc4848a117"),
        "name" : "Die Hard 2",
        "genre" : "action",
        "rating" : "9"
}
> cursor.next();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7eb82354a5c4cc4848a118"),
        "name" : "Die Hard 3",
        "genre" : "action",
        "rating" : "9"
}
> cursor.next();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b7eb82554a5c4cc4848a119"),
        "name" : "Die Hard 4",
        "genre" : "action",
        "rating" : "4"
}
> cursor.next();
2018-08-23T19:15:28.173+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: error hasNext: false :
DBQuery.prototype.next@src/mongo/shell/query.js:304:1
@(shell):1:1
>
```

Don't understand why `Die Hard 2` is fetched from cursor.

P.S.
I am using standalone installation of mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `cursor.next()` the first time, the first "batch" of documents is fetched from the server. At that time, "Die Hard 2" is still there and so it's included in the batch which is now stored in memory within the cursor. You then delete that document, but it's still in your cursor and subsequent calls to `cursor.next()` will return it, as you see.

Comment: Any documentation that can help he understand this further. Why cursor.count() updates correctly ?

Comment: Not that I've found. [`cursor.count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) isn't batch-related, so it always reflects the current count of documents referenced by the cursor.